# Deleting a stubborn folder

Tags: permissions, delete

I am trying to delete three files relating to a program install. I am listed as owner, and have all permissions, none of them are root files, they are all in the home folder. I tried deleting them normally and got the error, file can not be deleted. After a little searching I found the following thread here 
[How do I remove a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201775/how-do-i-remove-a-folder)
I have tried all of those suggestions, I type the information into the terminal, click enter, put in the password, click enter, and get the normal prompt, but the file is not deleted. 
This program did not install correctly and I am trying to reinstall, but it keeps telling me files cannot be copied because of these three files. What else can I do?

Comment: Maybe the program uses advanced attributes. Can you try lsattr on the directory and show the output for those 3 files?

Comment: Edit your question to show the exact command and error message.

Answer (score -1):

try shred

```
shred -vf <pathname>
```