# Create and remove directory using Terminal in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: command-line, 15.10

I created a directory using the following command

`mkdir TEST`.

Now I am trying to remove it using

`rm TEST` and `rm TEST/`

but it is showing the following error:

`cannot remove ‘TEST’: Is a directory` and `cannot remove ‘TEST/’: Is a directory`

Can anyone tell me how to remove this directory using terminal?

Comment: To remove directories you have to use the recursive option. try `rm -r TEST`. Then take a look at `man rm` for more information.

Comment: You can try `sudo rm -r -f /path/`  or `sudo rm -rf folderName` as here says :http://askubuntu.com/questions/201775/how-do-i-remove-a-folder and http://askubuntu.com/questions/217893/how-to-delete-a-non-empty-directory-in-terminal

Answer (score 1):

The command to remove a directory is `rmdir` not `rm`.

So you just type `rmdir TEST`.